# Stop ReSharper removing trailing spaces in XML comments in C# programs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I recently upgraded ReSharper to version Ultimate 2018.1, and now it deletes trailing spaces on XML comments in C# source files when I edit them. For example:

[image]

If I hit Return the trailing blank is removed from the line the text cursor was on, and I get this:

[image]

In case it isn't obvious, the trailing space after the word "couple" is gone, and I don't want that to happen, and it didn't happen prior to my upgrading ReSharper to the new version. (And just to be sure that ReSharper is the culprit I've tried suspending ReSharper, and then the problem goes away.)

I've tried fiddling with various ReSharper options, but without success.

EDIT:

(What I wrote in a previous edit was apparently wrong.)

I've filed a bug report on the JetBrains website: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-469733

If this bug bugs (ha, ha) you too, then you're welcome to vote for the bug report.

Comment: It probably doesn't help much, but I noticed that ReSharper only does this trimming when `Enter` is pressed on the line

Comment: I'm wondering if this is an XY problem: for example, perhaps a tool which processes the comments (like a documentation compiler) is not injecting space between the lines, and maybe *that* is the problem which actually needs solving.

Comment: I know that some documentation compilers (like Ghostdoc) don't respect multiple white spaces or new lines. In your example above I'd have to wrap that last line in <para></para> to actually get that formatting. I'm pretty sure intellisense works the same way. Perhaps r# is following the same logic. All that to say, I've not seen an option for this.  There's sections for new line options for c# and probably xml in the code formatting settings. You can type in the search box in options and it'll filter out the results making them easier to spot (if they do exist).